# Are there any memorization tricks to remembering the French verbs that are usually accompanied with "a" or "de"?

Tags: prépositions, verbes

As you know, the list of verbs that require no preposition (e.g., devoir), a specific prepositions (e.g., oublier de, refuser de, hésiter à, inviter à), or change meaning depending on the preposition (manquer à vs de) is long: https://www.thoughtco.com/french-verbs-with-prepositions-p2-1364548

Are there tips or tricks that can help a new learner remember these?

Answer (score 2):

There are no  rules.

> ([réf.](https://www.francaisavecpierre.com/a-ou-de-en-francais/)) Pour ne plus confondre les verbes qui se construisent avec À et ceux qui se construisent avec DE, il n’y a pas de secret: il faut les apprendre par cœur!

Sometimes either preposition is correct; this is true for the verb "continuer", for instance.

[image]

The particular preposition that a given verb calls for must be learned through the practice of reading, a practice the learner should constrain themselves into as soon as possible (gradual increase of the difficulty) and keep to as steadfastly as possible.

*Rule for verb that indicate motion*

> - from somewhere: DE
>   revenir de, partir de, arriver de,

> - to somewhere: À
>   revenir à, partir à, arriver à, aller à, se rendre à,

> - place where sb/sth is: À
>   être à (Brest, la montagne, l'école), vivre à,

There are certain principles that you will extract from a good dictionnary, such as the TLFi ([de](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de), [à](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0)). However, it is much better to learn by doing as much reading as you can (it is much more interesting and learning becomes much less painful).

Comment: Note that the choice of the prepositions may also vary locally due to the influence of dialects ("chercher quelque chose"/"chercher après quelque chose", or slangs, or because of social influences. What sounds like a mistake for some, is common for others ("le fils de Jacques"/"le fils à Jacques"). See https://www.er.uqam.ca/nobel/scilang/cesla02/Albanemj.PDF